# Symfony unit testing form, form using jquery datepicker

Tags: php, symfony, unit-testing, phpunit

I have a Roster entity in my Symfony project which contains two datetime fields.

Input field on FormType uses two single_text boxes, one for date one for time.

```
 $builder->add('serviceUserId', EntityType::class, array('class' => 'AppBundle:ServiceUser',
            'data' => $options['serviceUser']))
            ->add('rosterStartTime', DateTimeType::class,
                array('date_widget' => "single_text",
                    'time_widget' => "single_text",
                ))
            ->add('rosterEndTime', DateTimeType::class, array('date_widget' => "single_text",
                'time_widget' => "single_text",
            )
```

Can anyone tell me how to format the date I'm passing to this field in my Unit Test.

The nearest I've gotten is

```
      $client = static::createClient(array(), array(
        'PHP_AUTH_USER' => 'username',
        'PHP_AUTH_PW' => 'password',
    ));

    $date = new \DateTime('2015-04-01 08:00');

    //browse to an exsting service user and add a roster to that record
    $crawler = $client->request('GET', '/serviceuser/2');
    $crawler = $client->click($crawler->selectLink('Add New Roster')->link());

    // Fill in the form and submit it
    $form = $crawler->selectButton('Create')->form(array(
        'appbundle_roster[serviceUserId]' => 2,
        'appbundle_roster[rosterStartTime]'  => $date->format('yyyy-MM-dd'),

        'appbundle_roster[rosterStatus ]' => 1,
        'appbundle_roster[numberResourcesNeeded]' => 2,
        'appbundle_roster[customerId]' => 2,
    ));
```

It's failing with this error

```
     AppBundle\Tests\Controller\RosterControllerTest::testCompleteScenario
     InvalidArgumentException: Cannot set value on a compound field "appbundle_roster[rosterStartTime]".
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you try this instead:

```
'appbundle_roster[rosterStartTime][year]' => 2015,
'appbundle_roster[rosterStartTime][month]' => 4,
'appbundle_roster[rosterStartTime][day]' => 1,
```

It sounds (from error message) like it's rendering as selectable drop-down lists instead of a input text field.

Comment: Many thanks- unfortunately that returns Unreachable field [year]

Comment: So I'm really trying to help, but what is actually rendered? Can you check in a browser and then right click on the rosterStartTime field and see what the "name" is shown as? I'm presuming name is for example `appbundle_roster[rosterStartTime][year]`. That might help you figure out what to use.

Comment: Seems to be a date and time in two separate parts       <td><div id="appbundle_roster_rosterStartTime"><input type="date" id="appbundle_roster_rosterStartTime_date" name="appbundle_roster[rosterStartTime][date]" required="required" value="2017-03-04" /><input type="time" id="appbundle_roster_rosterStartTime_time" name="appbundle_roster[rosterStartTime][time]" required="required" value="08:50" /></div></td>

Comment: thanks @Alvin this worked        'appbundle_roster[rosterStartTime][date]'=>'2017-04-01',
            'appbundle_roster[rosterStartTime][time]'=>'08:00',
            'appbundle_roster[rosterEndTime][date]'=>'2017-04-01',
            'appbundle_roster[rosterEndTime][time]'=>'09:00'));

Comment: I was just going to suggest something like that! Glad you got it working!

Comment: thanks Alvin. Didn't link to look at the HTML (newb to this testing mallarkey!) Appreciate your help